# How to get dashed Horizontal Progressbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-shapedrawable

I need to design a dashed progressbar as shown in attached.

[image]

This is what I have done so far, It displays a normal progressbar with two different colors, one for progress and another for other.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_progress_bar_green"
    />
```

And bg_progress_bar_green is here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#E0E1EA" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#66BA6B" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

And this is how I update the progressbar :

```
 progressBar.setProgress(numOfHours);
```

How do I get dashed line of bar as shown?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library for your work [Step Progress Bar](https://github.com/marcokstephen/StepProgressBar). I'm providing code in case of link changed.

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.marcok.stepprogressbar:stepprogressbar:1.0.1'
}
```

**Usage**

```
 <com.marcok.stepprogressbar.StepProgressBar
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/stepProgressBar"
    app:cumulativeDots="false"
    app:activeDotIndex="0"
    app:activeDotColor="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
    app:inactiveDotColor="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    app:activeDotIcon="@drawable/active_dot.png"
    app:inactiveDotIcon="@drawable/inactive_dot.png"
    app:numberDots="6"
    app:dotSize="20dp"
    app:spacing="20dp"/>
```

- If dot icons are provided, they override dot colors
- Layout height is irrelevant and determined by the dotSize

**Java Code**

- To move to the next dot or previous dot:

  `StepProgressBar mStepProgressBar =(StepProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.stepProgressBar);
  mStepProgressBar.next();
  mStepProgressBar.previous();`

  - To set the dots to be cumulative (all dots <= the specified index will show as active), call `setCumulativeDots(true)`
  - Calling `setCurrentProgressDot(-1)` will prevent any dots from showing as active. Any lower values will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsExeption.`
  - Other methods:

  `setCurrentProgressDot();
  setNumDots();
  setActiveColor();
  setInactiveColor();
  setActiveDrawable();
  setInactiveDrawable();`

**DRAWABLES FOR RECTANGLE PROGRESS**

use these two drawbles..

[image: inactive_dot.png] inactive_dot.png

[image: active_dot.png] active_dot.png

Comment: I need to show the progressed rectangles in green and rest all other in gray. How do we make multiple dots/rectangles activate using this library?

Comment: @SANTHOSH i have changed whole library.. its a new library that perfectsly suitable for your work

Comment: @AbhishekSingh hi! Can you please share your library?

Comment: @D7ILeucoH above code will work for you . privously I posted different answer first and changed to this answer. This answer will perfectly solve the question.